# Sometimes element, sometimes jQuery object returned?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm diving into jQuery for some days now and everthing seems to be quite fine - but there is on thing I'm always confused about:
Sometimes, a jQuery selection returns an array of plain DOM-elements and sometimes I get a this array-like jQuery-object.

For example selecting with an ID:

```
var note = $('#note')
console.log(note.val());
```

works quite fine - it is a jQuery-wrapped Element I can work with all the jQuery methods.

But having to select it via the class like

```
var notes = $('.notes');
_.each(notes, function (element) {
    element = $(element);
    console.log(element.val());
});
```

seems to be me quite ugly - is there not a simple way to return me always a jQuery wrapped set?

I guess it relates to performance considerations but I'd like to get a way to select via non-ID selectors and working with wrapped jQuery objects right away.

Thanks

Comment: First get its type and then decide how to work with it: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.type/

Comment: jQuery provides the `each` method to iterate through a jQuery object and return it. Any reason why you can't use that? EDIT: Unless you're talking about within your underscore `each`. In that case, both return the element and you need to re-wrap it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are missing is that when you create a collection with `$(selector)` it creates a jQuery object that contains an array of the DOM elements represented by the selector.

That object would be huge if each element of the collection was then in turn wrapped in jQuery object.

In short, there is no magic way to do what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

You are getting JQuery wrapped set which is array with all the elements inside of it. Running `$.each` on array iterates over these elements one by one.

in other words

`$('.notes')[0]` will get you first element in that selection.

In this specific case if you are looking for value you could simply do `console.log(element.value);`

Comment: .val() was just used as an example - more complex, jQuery-function are usually to be invoked :)